# How to avoid creating a category to test a private method? - objective C

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, testing, categories

I want to test a private method in an object, a solution to do that is creating a category in the tests class file including the private methods to test.

```
// Simple Category for testing private methods
@interface CVPOrdersMapPresenter (Testing)
- (void)refreshMap;
@end
```

It has a problem... what happen when that private method change its signature in the class? the test breaks.

How can I avoid doing that and still test the private method?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to update the test if the signature changes regardless of whether the method is private. I don't understand the real difficulty here.

Comment: Yes, you're right but I want to know that the signature has changed and I want to know the new signature name. I do prefer don't have to search in my code what has changed and the new signatures, I want the compiler to advise me.